# Cannot pass an Integer in an Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass an Integer (from an edittext) to another activity through an intent.
When the user clicks a button, the text in the edittext will transform into a string and then into an int, then the int will be sent through an intent to another activity, but i have to use the int after that.

Here the activity sending the intent:

```
public class HomeActivityPro extends ActionBarActivity {
 private InterstitialAd interstitial;
 EditText conttext = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.texthome );
 Button buttone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);
 String maxom = conttext.getText().toString();
 int maxam = Integer.parseInt(maxom);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);

    View.OnClickListener maxim = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View view) {
            Intent wall = new Intent(HomeActivityPro.this, GuessOne.class);
            wall.putExtra("maxPressed", maxam);
            startActivity(wall);

        }
    };
    buttone.setOnClickListener(maxim);
```

Here the activity receiving it:

```
public class GuessOne extends ActionBarActivity {
int randone;
int contone;
int wall = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_guess_one);
    wall = getIntent().getIntExtra("maxPressed", -1);
    randone = (int) (Math.random()*10+1);
    contone = 0;
```

}

Here i'm using it:

```
public void guessone (View view){
contone++;
     textcontone.setText(getString(R.string.attempts) + "" + contone);

    if (contone >= wall ){
        resultaone.setText("You Failed" + " " + wall);
        Toast.makeText(this, "You Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

When i use the app, the value of the int is always -1. Where i am wrong.

Comment: as is, you app cannot start.

Comment: @jacob You can't use `findViewById` without setting the xml to the activity. That means you need to use `findViewById` method only after you have called `setContentView`. There are few other errors too. Please see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `findViewById` without setting the xml to the activity. That means you need to use `findViewById` method only after you have called `setContentView`.

Also you need to read the EditText text value once you click on the button otherwise it always will be null/empty.

Do this

```
public class HomeActivityPro extends ActionBarActivity {
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
EditText conttext;
Button buttone;
String maxom;
int maxam = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);

conttext = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.texthome );
buttone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);


View.OnClickListener maxim = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view) {
        maxom = conttext.getText().toString();
        maxam = Integer.parseInt(maxom);
        Intent wall = new Intent(HomeActivityPro.this, GuessOne.class);
        wall.putExtra("maxPressed", maxam);
        startActivity(wall);

    }
};
buttone.setOnClickListener(maxim);
```

Comment: `Also you need to read the EditText text value once you click on the button otherwise it always will be null/empty` is that really true? (do not answer Sir)

Comment: OP doesn't have any other place to read it. This statement is true only for given code. Where else do you propose to read it?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1**

Put this in the on click listener instead:

```
String maxom = conttext.getText().toString();
int maxam = Integer.parseInt(maxom);
```

You want the values to be read at the time you click the button not when you open the activity, correct?

**Problem 2**

The following needs to be after `setContentView` in `onCreate`:

```
conttext = (EditText) findViewById ( R.id.texthome );
buttone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttone);
```

Keep the declarations where they are. Just the declarations:

```
EditText conttext;
Button buttone;
```

**Note**

Follow the same pattern in all your activities. Declare views as field variables, assign them in `onCreate` after `setContentLayout`. Get the values at the time they're needed.

Comment: See the updated answer. Keep the view variables out of any method. just as you originally did. Declare them outside, assign them inside.

Comment: See the answer from @Rohit5k2. That's basically what I said served on a silver platter. Understand it though, don't just copy/paste code blindly.

Comment: How are you checking it? Does the `GuessOne` activity which accepts the value have modified `launchMode` in the manifest?

Comment: Don't think, verify. Always. Now, how are you checking the value you receive?

Answer (score 1):

> public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)
>
> Added in API level 1 Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> Parameters name   The name of the desired item. defaultValue  the value
>   to be returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the
>   given name. Returns the value of an item that previously added with
>   putExtra() or the default value if none was found. See Also
>   putExtra(String, int)

This means that no int was found when you called `getIntExtra(valueName, defaultValue);` so the default value was chosen.

You should check to see what your `maxam` value is before you call the new activity.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity you receive it:

```
wall = getIntent().getIntExtra("maxPressed");
```

Comment: I got the error: getIntExtra in Intent cannot be applied to string

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: by getInt and String.valueOf

```
private static final String IMGID = "ImgID";

if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMGID)) {
 //Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMG)).into(mImg);
 Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(String.valueOf(IMGID))).into(mImg);
}
```